# openldap index existing values

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a ldap database that has been used for some time. naturally it is full on entries.

I recently tried to set up an index for uid to help searching, i added the following to my slapd.conf file

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
database bdb
suffix "dc=domain,dc=net"
directory /var/lib/ldap
index uid eq,pres
```

I then ran slapindex

```
slapindex -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -b "dc=jhc,dc=net" uid
```

But this didnt seem to do it, i dont know if this part is correct but to make any progress the only thing that worked seemed to be adding the following line to a db ldif file in /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/

```
olcDbIndex: uid pres,eq
```

I then ran the slapindex again and started ldap. Searching for a uid is now much faster but doesnt give me a result on entries that where already in the db only new entries show when i do an ldapsearch and filter for the uid, for reference the search is below but i have taken out details of my ldap server

```
ldapsearch  "cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=net" -b "cn=users,dc=domain,dc=net" "(uid=newuser)"
```

What am i missing to get entries that already exist to be indexed?

Comment: As its name implies, OLC (for online configuration) is read and loaded on the fly. However changes to `slapd.conf` is read when you (re)start the server. The second thing is that running `slapindex`, `slapcat`, `slapadd` must be done offline. Did you stop slapd before running `slapindex` ?

Comment: I did stop slapd before running slapindex. Ive done lots of searching online to try find the solution and all i can find is this - "slapd does not create the index automatically after adding the line to slapd.conf. New entries will be indexed but existing entries will not. slapd will search the index for values and since the old values have not been indexed.
Solution:
Use ldbmcat to generate an LDIF for your database. Be sure to output item numbers (it is the default). Then use ldif2index to generate an index for a specific value. Restart the database and you are all set!"
see next comment

Comment: From what i can tell this solution is outdated as ldbmcat and ldif2index are not something used anymore but i cannot find what the new version of these commands are and how they should be run in order to update the index.

Comment: @a.smith Yes this statement is outdated. _`slapindex` is used to regenerate slapd(8) indices based upon the current contents of a database. It opens the given database determined by the database number or suffix and updates the indices for all values of all attributes of all entries. If a list of specific attributes is provided on the command line, only the indices for those attributes will be regenerated.  Databases configured as subordinate of this one are also re-indexed, unless -g is specified._ If you changed your backend (bdb/hdb/mdb...) though, you'd need to use slapcat/slapadd.

Comment: @EricLavault The online configuration is used *instead* of `slapd.conf`, which isn't read *at all* when using OLC.

Comment: Well, yes obviously as its name implies, online is not offline but thank you.. I should have made it clear from the start : mixing both is nonsense, which also might explain how you landed in this situation. Nb. "_slapindex, slapcat, slapadd must be done offline._", here offline means offline (= slapd not running), not in offline config (slapd.conf ) mode.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this issue the solution is to essential migrate your DB and add in the new index attribute to the config.ldif file, for me this was done by running

```
slapcat -n 0 -l config.ldif
slapcat -n 2 -l data.ldif
```

Then remove the files in /etc/openldap/slapd.d and /usr/local/openldap/

Edit the the config.ldif file and add in your index value, if you have other index values just copy them for me it looked like this

```
olcDbIndex uid eq
```

The final step is to add your DB back with your two ldif files

```
slapadd -c -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -n 0 -l config.ldif
slapadd -c -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -n 2 -l data.ldif
```

You should be able to start ldap now, make sure your ldap user is the owner of the openldap folders and its contents.

Comment: Using slapcat/slapadd (you're welcome) is a workaround which does not explain how you landed in this situation where slapindex has no effect on your existing entries. It only suggests you messed up with the existing database or switched from one backend to another, and if it's not the case, then we still don't know how/why slapindex does not work as expected in your case, and especially how one can prevent that from happening.

Comment: From my understanding or at least from what ive read slapindex does not index existing entries. in version 2.4 at least

Comment: Where did you read that ?

Comment: The outdated solution mentioned above but that still references slapindex